# Java array sum and print not working

Tags: java, arrays, sum

I have all of the code running correctly except I can't get commission/commissionRate to work correctly. I pulled the code out and ran it by itself and seemed to get the calculations to work.

So clearly when I pass it to displayTotals it doesn't display anything.

Also, on a side note...I prefer the look of my { on the following line. Is this an issue? In my textbook and according to my professor its acceptable, but I got scolded by another user on my last post for doing it.

I'm not being disrespectful...I'm just wondering why?

Thanks,

```
/*
* Anthony Vincenzo Laginess
* CIT 130 HMW 08 Arrays
* 10/19/16
* Time Spent: 
*/
package cit130mhmw08_laginess;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CIT130MHMW08_Laginess 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Please enter the total number of dealers: ");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    int numDealers = input.nextInt();
    numDealers = numberOfDealers(numDealers);
    String[] dealerNames = new String[numDealers];
    double[] dealerSales = new double[numDealers];
    double[] commissionRate = new double[numDealers];

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Please enter the required data for each of your dealers: %n");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    dataCalculation(numDealers, dealerNames, dealerSales);

    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println("Dealer Totals: ");
    System.out.println("----------------");
    displayTotals(numDealers, dealerNames, dealerSales, commissionRate);

    System.out.println("----------------");
    System.out.println("Remaining Totals: ");
    System.out.println("----------------");

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Dealership Sales Total: ");
    dealershipSales(numDealers, dealerSales);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Dealership Sales Averages: ");
    dealerSalesAvg(numDealers, dealerSales);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Dealership Total Commission: ");
    dealershipTotalCommission(numDealers, commissionRate);

    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
}//main

//METHOD 1
public static int numberOfDealers(int dealers)
{
    int results;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(dealers < 0 || dealers > 30)
    {
        System.out.printf("%nEnter a valid number of dealers: %n");
        dealers = input.nextInt();  
    }
    results = dealers;
    return results;
}//number of dealers methods

//METHOD 2
public static void dataCalculation(int numDealers, String[] dealerNames, double[] dealerSales)
{   
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.printf("%nEnter the names of the dealers:%n ");

        for(int i = 0; i < numDealers; i++)
        {
            String names =input.nextLine();
            dealerNames[i]= names;
        }
    System.out.printf("%nEnter their sales totals: %n");

        for(int i = 0; i < numDealers; i++)
        {
            double sales = input.nextDouble();
            dealerSales[i] = sales;
        }
}//data calculations

//METHOD 3
public static void commission(int numDealers, double[] dealerSales)
{
    //Create array
    double[] commissionRate = new double[numDealers]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < numDealers; i++)
    {
            commissionRate[i] = dealerSales[i];

        if(commissionRate[i] > 0 && commissionRate[i] < 5000)
           commissionRate[i] = commissionRate[i] * 0.08; 
        else if(commissionRate[i] > 5000 && commissionRate[i] < 15000)
            commissionRate[i] = commissionRate[i] * 0.15;
        else if(commissionRate[i] > 15000)
            commissionRate[i] =  commissionRate[i] * 0.20;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < numDealers; i++)
    {
        System.out.printf("%n$%5.2f" , commissionRate[i]);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}//commission method 

public static void dealershipSales(int numDealers, double[] dealerSales)
{
    //Create array
    double dealershipSalesTotal = 0; 

    for(int i = 0; i < numDealers; i++)
    {
        dealershipSalesTotal += dealerSales[i];  

    }
        System.out.printf("%n$%5.2f" , dealershipSalesTotal);
        System.out.println("");
}//dealership sales

public static void dealerSalesAvg(int numDealers, double[] dealerSales)
{
    double dealerSalesAvgTotal = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numDealers; i++)
    {
        dealerSalesAvgTotal += dealerSales[i];
    }
        System.out.printf("%n$%5.2f" , dealerSalesAvgTotal / numDealers);
        System.out.println("");
}//dealership sales averages

public static void dealershipTotalCommission(int numDealers, double[] commissionRate)
{
    double totalCommission = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < numDealers; i++)
    {
            totalCommission += commissionRate[i] * 100;
    }
        System.out.printf("%n$%5.2f" , totalCommission);
        System.out.println("");
}//total commission for the dealership

public static void displayTotals(int numDealers, String[] dealerNames, double[] dealerSales, double[] commissionRate)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < numDealers; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(dealerNames[i]);
        System.out.printf("$%5.2f" , dealerSales[i]);
        System.out.printf("%n$%5.2f" , commissionRate[i]);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}//display totals  
}//class
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your `commission` method, therefore it's code does not get executed.

Even if you did: you don't pass the `commissionRate` array into it nor do you return the locally created `commissionRate` array, so your calculations there are lost for the `displayTotals` and `dealershipTotalCommission` methods.

---

Just to repeat: the `commissionRate` array created and used here:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ...
    double[] commissionRate = new double[numDealers];
    ...
    displayTotals(numDealers, dealerNames, dealerSales, commissionRate);
    ...
    dealershipTotalCommission(numDealers, commissionRate)
}
```

is not the same array as the array created here:

```
public static void commission(int numDealers, double[] dealerSales)
{
    //Create array
    double[] commissionRate = new double[numDealers];
    ...
}
```

---

If you want your to code to work you have to call the `commission` method at all and pass it the `commissionRate` as a parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ...
    double[] commissionRate = new double[numDealers];
    ...
    commission(numDealers, dealerSales, commissionRate);
    ...
    displayTotals(numDealers, dealerNames, dealerSales, commissionRate);
    ...
    dealershipTotalCommission(numDealers, commissionRate)
}

public static void commission(int numDealers, double[] dealerSales, double[] commissionRate)
{
    //do not create a new array here!
    ...
}
```

---

On a side note: instead of calling `System.out.println("");` you can just call `System.out.println();`

Comment: But I do have commissionRate being passed into displayTotals and dealershipTotalCommission...

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the placement of the braces. Either style is acceptable. Placing the opening brace to the right is usual for Java programs, and the Java Coding Conventions (from the 1990s) use that style. C# in Visual Studio places the opening brace on a line of its own.

The IDE you are using allows you to have your code formatted automatically. In the settings you can configure your preferred style. As long as you stick to this style and have your whole code formatted in the same style, everything is fine.